# Does udev need sudo in run?

Tags: sudo, root, udev

I've got a `udev` rule that is properly matching, but it is not executing the command in the `RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"` properly. If I change that to be some sort of test shell script then it works fine.

If I run `synclient TouchpadOff=1` from the command line I get no return and it doesn't work. However, adding `sudo` to that line disables the touchpad as intended.

Is udev not executing this command with superuser permissions?

Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synclient` depends on X server to work. See `man synclient`. So you need to define the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables of the current running server.

If you are using just a single user account with simple server setup, try this:

```
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority synclient TouchpadOff=1'"
```

Change `<username>` to your username.