# Which rights do scripts have that are triggered by a udev rule?

Tags: permissions, udev

From what I understand I can create a `udev` rule to run a script e.g. when a USB device is plugged in:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0123", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0815", SYMLINK+="mydevice", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/path/to/my/script.sh"
```

My question is now, which rights does this script have?

I found two questions that relate to the subject:

- [Does udev need sudo in run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672320/does-udev-need-sudo-in-run): the problem was elsewhere and the question in the title was never answered
- [Notification not showing up by script run by udev rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859353/notification-not-showing-up-by-script-run-by-udev-rules): an answer says to “use `sudo` to run `notify-send` as same user (Not as `root`)”, which to me implies that a) the script has the right to `sudo` and b) would run as `root` if you don’t specify the user

I could not find any documentation that went beyond stating that the `RUN` parameter exists for `udev` rules concerning its rights and abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, unless otherwise specified, programs started by something are run as the same user as that something. In this case, that's `systemd-udevd`, and  it runs as root, so the programs are run as root (which is why you need to use `sudo` to run as another user).

Even so, [there are some limitations](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#RUN%7Btype%7D):

> Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on `systemd-udevd.service`.